# Modify footline in Beamer - R Markdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown, beamer

I'm actually using the `CambridgeUS` theme for my Beamer using RMarkdown.

```
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "CambridgeUS"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{color}
  - \usepackage{amsmath}
  - \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
```

I wanna know how to delete the date in the footline and how to change the value taken as the full name (author) to only take last name.

It's possible using only tex as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66995/modify-footer-of-slides) but I don't succeed using RMarkdown.

Do you already face this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the date from the footline, you could specify en empty optional argument in `\date[]{\today}`.

To show only the last name in the footline, define a short version for the author: `\author[Smith]{Jack Smith}`

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\date[]{\today}
\author[Smith]{Jack Smith}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

The identical code also works in rmarkdown:

```
---
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "CambridgeUS"
header-includes:
  - \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  - \date[]{\today}
  - \author[Smith]{Jack Smith}
---

test
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time, I'll try it, but not sure how to do so on Rmarkdown and not latex directly